# Как спарсить string в define?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Есть JSON файл, в котором храниться код сообщения типа WM (0x020B, 0x020C и т.п.)

В условии мне необходимо его сравнить с WPARAM. Если я правильно понимаю, то сделать это можно только с define.

```
if (wParam == "код сообщения из JSON файла")
        {               
            return -1; 
        }
```

Вопрос: Как мне реализовать данное условие? Как мне его правильно сравнить?

Comment: [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) - переводит строку в число, третьим параметром передаете 16, т.к. система счисления шестнадцатиричная. `wParam` сравниваете с результатом `std::stoi`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: О каком "define" идет речь и при чем оно здесь?